# Pass ng-model from parent to controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to pass ng-model located in a different HTML scope to controller when a button is clicked. It works if the button is in the same scope as the ng-model, but I want to have the button in the header.

Case 1. This works:

**HTML**

```
<header>       
</header>
<content>
    <label>
         <input ng-model="text">
    </label>
    <button ng-click="save(text)">
       Save
    </button>
</content>
```

Case 2. This does not work:

**HTML**

```
<header>       
    <button ng-click="save(text)">
       Save
    </button>
</header>
<content>
    <label>
         <input ng-model="text">
    </label>
</content>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.save = function(text) {
    console.log(text); // Undefined in case 2.
};
```

To my understanding the ng-model is better suited pointing to an object key. So I tried this:

**HTML**

```
<header> 
    <button ng-click="save(text)">
       Save
    </button>      
</header>
<content>
    <label>
         <input ng-model="obj.text">
    </label>
</content>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.obj = {};
    console.log(obj.text); // Still undefined
};
```

How can I pass ng-model when the button is located in the header is clicked to controller?

Comment: Is it possible to add plunker/fiddle?

Comment: create $scope.obj outside of function save. You declaring obj as empty on each click

Comment: Ivan, Yes, you're right. This fixed my problem! Thank you!